# How to add simple static RTF to a .NET RichTextBox in C++CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, rtf

I am having trouble adding some basic RTF text to a RichTextBox object I have in my .NET C++CLI Windows Forms application. All I need to do is fill my RTF box with two or three "paragraphs" of STATIC text with some text bold, some italic, and some regular and all of it Arial font of some fixed size.

For example, I just want the following

**Header 1**: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. *Some italics at the end...*

(blank line)

**Header 2**: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco

I looked all over and found some stuff for VB.NET, ASP, even C# (which I can usually translate into C++CLI), but I either get weird run-time errors about the "format" of my RTF or everything is bold with the `{` and `}` symbols and other weird characters showing up.

For example, I tried `myRichTextBox->Rtf = "{\rtf1\ansi\bHeader\b0: This is a test}"` but got the run-time "format" error. Some places suggested adding the `@` token but this is unrecognized in C++CLI at least.

If someone could just suggest the right way to format the string (or a `String^ str` that I can pass to my RTF box) to get the lorem ipsum I showed above I'd really appreciate it! Just need bold, italics, one font, one size, ALL STATIC text, nothing programmatic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your string, the compiler doesn't interpret it like you think:

```
myRichTextBox->Rtf = "{\rtf1\ansi\bHeader\b0: This is a test}";
```

for instance `\r` in interpreted as a carriage return. That's why you've seen suggestions of using `@` (verbatim strings) in C#:

```cs
// This is C# syntax
myRichTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\bHeader\b0: This is a test}";
myRichTextBox.Rtf = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\bHeader\\b0: This is a test}";
```

These two C# lines are equivalent. The `@` tells the compiler to ignore all escapes in the string.

So, what can you do in C++/CLI?

Well... either simply escape the backslashes:

```
myRichTextBox->Rtf = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\bHeader\\b0: This is a test}";
```

Or, preferably, you can use the equivalent of C#'s verbatim strings: [raw strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx):

```
// foo is an optional delimiter
myRichTextBox->Rtf = LR"foo({\rtf1\ansi\bHeader\b0: This is a test})foo";
```

Comment: thanks. For some reason, my project doesn't recognize "LR" and gives me the squiggly red error underline and won't compile, which is really strange. I'm in VS 2012 and so far I have had no such problems. Also, when I tried escaping the backslashes the "\\bHeader\\b0" was just missing and the text just started with the colon ":" and "This is a test". Do you think that this is probably an RTF syntax thing or am I doing something wrong in .NET?

Comment: Well... VS2012 doesn't support the raw string syntax so that explains it. You need at least VS2013. As for your display issue, that's probably due to bad RTF syntax. I don't know RTF syntax but from what I can glance from wikipedia, you could try something like `{\rtf1\ansi{\b Header:} This is a test}` (escaping the backslashes of course). MS Word seems to recognize that just fine.